# .Net Reflector crash

Tags: crash, reflector, .net-reflector

I have problem with my .Net Reflector 8.3 application. When I double click it doesn't start and generates error.

[image]

`.Net Reflector has just thrown an exception: Could not load file or assembly '{a755eaf2-c07e-4b95-b1ee-a3437dfa4635}', PublicKeyToken=3e56350693f7355e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I am using Windows 8.0 x64. I've also enabled .Net framework 3.5 and 4.5.1 installed on my machine. I've searched every where and find nothing to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels to find help.  Picking up the phone is the quickest way.

Comment: RedGate's forum for Reflector is at: http://forums.reflector.net/index.html